# Scope of method defined inside another method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Consider the following code:

```
class Emotion
  def confused?
    def confused?
      'yes'
    end
    'no'
  end
end

am_i = Emotion.new

am_i.confused? # => "no"
am_i.confused? # => "yes"

5.times.map { Emotion.new.confused? } # => ["yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes"]
```

Explanation:

1. Running `confused?` the first time returns `"no"` and *re-defines* itself.
2. Running `confused?` the second time invokes the new method that returns `"yes"`.

Though the above functionality is clear, I am not sure how both methods are being defined to the same **scope**.

The reason I ask is because:

- A variable cannot be accessed in similar fashion inside and outside a method; for instance: if I define `@variable` inside and outside a method it has different meanings.
- I have learned that method definition changes `self`. Won't the inside definition of the `confused?` method have a different scope in comparison with the outside definition?
- How does `def` actually determine where to define the method?

Comment: Ruby does not have nested methods. When you call the method the first time, it executes its body and defines the second method. The next time you call the method, you get a different result because the inner method was defined, and takes precedence. As mentioned in the earlier comment Emotion.new.confused will always return "no".

Comment: I have *actually tested this* on ruby 2.2.0, and `loop { p Emotion.new.confused? }` prints `"no"` and then a stream of `"yes"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A variable cannot be accessed in similar fashion inside and outside a method; for instance: if I define @variable inside and outside a method it has different meanings.

When setting instance variables with `@x = y` syntax, the instance variables are set for `self`.

> I have learned that method definition changes self. Won't the inside definition of the confused? method have a different scope in comparison with the outside definition?

The scope *can* change, but in this case it doesn't. The value of `self` inside a method is always the object that the method is being called on. In both of your `confused?` method definitions, `self` is an instance of `Emotion`.

> How does def actually determine where to define the method?

The answer to this (at least in MRI) is actually somewhat unintuitive. Every scope has a reference to a "default definee" object which is not necessarily related to `self` and is always an instance of `Module`. `def` in that scope will define a method for the default definee. The most trivial way to get the default definee in ruby code is this:

```
eval("def __m; end; m = method(:__m); undef __m; m.owner")
```

For example, running that at the top level of a ruby program returns `Object`. So, the default definee for the toplevel scope is `Object`.

Here is some code which can hopefully answer your questions about scopes:

```
# `self` is the toplevel object
# default definee is `Object`

class X
  # `self` is X
  # default definee is also X

  @a = 1 # defines instance variable @a for `X`

  def y # defines method 'y' on X

    # `self` is an instance of X
    # default definee is X

    @b = 2 # defines instance variable @b for an instance of `X`

    def z # defines method 'z' on X

      # `self` is still an instance of X
      # default definee is still X

      @c = 3 # defines instance variable @c for an instance of `X`

    end
  end

  class << self
    # `self` is the metaclass of X
    # default definee is also the metaclass of X

    @d = 4 # defines instance variable @d for the metaclass of X
  end
end
```

It is important to remember that **methods** are always stored in instances of `Module`, where as **instance variables** can be stored in any object (excluding primitives like `nil` or booleans or integers).

Comment: Small nit. There are no primitive types in Ruby. Everything is an object, including nil, booleans, and integers.

Comment: @Fred: By "primitive", I mean objects which are not stored in memory (and so can't have instance variables or metaclasses). They are still objects, but lack those properties. Try doing this, you will get an error: `nil.instance_eval { @xyz = 123 }`

Comment: I didn't know the concept of default definee! Thanks, will read more. As you mentioned its surely not intuitive and hardly do any Metaprogramming resources mention about it.